# mwtp t-statistics calculation in R

Tags: r, regression

I have two questions: 
first, my model is as below:

--

```
Call:
mlogit(formula = rank ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + V4 + V5 | income + age + 
    education + gender | (V2) * (age + gender + education), data = S, 
    method = "nr", print.level = 0)

Frequencies of alternatives:
      1       2       3 
0.32407 0.26905 0.40688 

nr method
6 iterations, 0h:0m:2s 
g'(-H)^-1g = 1.95E-05 
successive function values within tolerance limits 

Coefficients :
                  Estimate  Std. Error  t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
2:(intercept)   9.8930e-01  8.8874e-01   1.1131   0.26565    
3:(intercept)  -2.3067e-01  1.1345e+00  -0.2033   0.83888    
V1              5.1885e-01  7.7484e-02   6.6962  2.14e-11 ***
V2              3.8837e-01  8.1893e-01   0.4742   0.63533    
V3             -1.2537e-01  5.4441e-02  -2.3029   0.02129 *  
V4              6.5604e-01  6.7002e-02   9.7914 < 2.2e-16 ***
V5             -2.2937e-04  7.9217e-06 -28.9550 < 2.2e-16 ***
2:income       -3.1801e-04  2.6299e-04  -1.2092   0.22659    
3:income        9.5959e-05  2.2721e-04   0.4223   0.67278    
2:age           3.7294e-03  1.4435e-02   0.2584   0.79614    
3:age          -3.8454e-03  1.8257e-02  -0.2106   0.83318    
2:education    -1.4570e-01  1.2416e-01  -1.1735   0.24059    
3:education    -6.9009e-02  1.5606e-01  -0.4422   0.65836    
2:gender       -2.0298e-01  2.4921e-01  -0.8145   0.41536    
3:gender       -2.1425e-01  3.1674e-01  -0.6764   0.49877    
2:V2           -7.3716e-01  1.4334e+00  -0.5143   0.60707    
3:V2            3.3264e-01  1.4608e+00   0.2277   0.81987    
1:V2:age        1.0054e-02  1.3341e-02   0.7537   0.45105    
2:V2:age        2.6575e-04  1.3806e-02   0.0192   0.98464    
3:V2:age        2.0324e-02  1.5311e-02   1.3274   0.18438    
1:V2:gender     2.4816e-01  2.2905e-01   1.0835   0.27861    
2:V2:gender     4.0128e-01  2.4127e-01   1.6632   0.09628 .  
3:V2:gender     3.2951e-01  2.6684e-01   1.2349   0.21687    
1:V2:education -3.0021e-02  1.1275e-01  -0.2662   0.79005    
2:V2:education  2.0999e-01  1.1936e-01   1.7593   0.07853 .  
3:V2:education -2.5188e-02  1.3098e-01  -0.1923   0.84751    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Log-Likelihood: -2305.6
McFadden R^2:  0.43745 
Likelihood ratio test : chisq = 3585.8 (p.value = < 2.22e-16)
```

--

V5 is monetary variable. I'd like to calculate MWTP, but V2 is not significant itself but significant with interaction terms. 
(1) Is it OK for calculating MWTP of V2 itself?

if I apply mwtp function in support.CEs, it shows like this

```
       MWTP     2.5%    97.5%
V1  2262.03  1636.98  2887.08
V2  1693.18 -5301.17  8687.52
.. 

method = Delta
```

(2) How can I calculate T-statistics of each MWTP ?

I'll be looking forward for your kind answers.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your dataset S?

Comment: S <- mlogit.data(stata_data, shape="long", alt.levels=c(1,2,3), choice="rank", ranked=TRUE)